# PHP mysql. Trying to retrieve LIKE query using ->bind_param

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to do a search on my database where it returns results based on exact surnames and first names with the initial of the name entered in an input box.  For instance, if the user enters `Simon Burns` it will return all users with the initial `S` for the first name and `Burns` for the Surname. Here is my code.

Sorry if this has been covered before but I cannot find a simple answer that works.

```
$firstname = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'firstname', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$surname = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'surname', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

$prep_query = "SELECT id, firstname, surname, profilepic, Gender, StartYear, EndYear, CircaStart, CircaEnd, JnrHouse, SnrHouse
                   FROM people WHERE firstname LIKE ? AND surname = ?";
$namecheckresult = $connection->prepare($prep_query);

// Return all matches wether registered on not
if ($namecheckresult) 
    {
    $initial = $firstname[0];   
    $namecheckresult->bind_param( 'ss',  $initial . '%', $surname);
    $namecheckresult->execute();
    $namecheckresult->store_result();
    $namecheckresult->bind_result($id, $first, $last, $ProfilePic, $Gender, $StartYear, $EndYear, $CircaStart, $CircaEnd, $JnrHouse, $SnrHouse);
```

Comment: Erm, is there any error code either from PHP or MySQL being returned?

Comment: ( ! ) Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in

Comment: From [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php): " Binds **variables** to a prepared statement as parameters" (emphasis mine). Let me check if I can find a proper duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

You have mixed up your 2 parameters

Change it to

```
$p1 = '%'.$initial;
$namecheckresult->bind_param( 'ss',  $p1 , $surname);
```

Or you may want to put the `%` on the front and back of `$initial` like this

```
$p1 = "%$initial%";
$namecheckresult->bind_param( 'ss',  $p1 , $surname);
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply but that does nor work either. Here is the the error i get with that piece of code.    ( ! ) Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference

Comment: Ok, try that instead, I made a bit of a woopsy

Comment: Yes, thanks RiggsFolly worked it out myself eventually and is the same as your second answer.

Answer (score -2):

I have now worked out the answer.

changing  $initial = $firstname[0];

to

$initial = "%$firstname[0]%";

works.

Hope this helps others.

Comment: Well, actually as written on http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php the variable has to be a reference. So you may not build a string together in the argument section. A change of `$initial = $firstname[0]; $namecheckresult->bind_param( 'ss',  $initial . '%', $surname);` to `$initial = $firstname[0].'%'; $namecheckresult->bind_param( 'ss',  $initial, $surname);` should do the work ...

Comment: I tried the above you posted and that still throws an error. My solution does not and works.